# Ask for a quick update method for records that containing duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with millions of records, but each object could have multiple columns that share the same values while some other columns have different values.

Example: A person has the same email address and the same mobile number, but has different transaction histories, which will generate multiple records in the table.

I want to update the table based on the email address and mobile number. Since multiple records have the same email address and mobile number, the updated column will get the same result.

My code:

```
UPDATE person 
SET info = concat (email, mobile);
```

But this code will have a full table scale, and update the records one by one, which is very slow, because the table size is large.

I wonder if there is a quick way to update the field, ie using aggregation method?

FYI, I work on MYSQL 8.0 workbench.

Comment: I've tried creating an intermediate table to solve the problem, but I would prefer avoiding the intermediate table. Thanks

Comment: Add a WHERE clause to limit the rows affected. A good SQL tutorial will help you learn how WHERE works.

Comment: I need to update the whole table. How do I use where clause to limit the rows affected? Please kindly give me a hint.

Comment: You can't update every row in the table without full table scale. Aggregation will not change the fact that every single row is being updated. I'm not sure what you're looking for here: *I need to update every single row without actually touching every single row to change it* isn't logical. It sounds likely that your table design is flawed, and fixing that issue will probably make this question's problem disappear. If you fix the table so that there aren't any duplicate values, you don't have as many rows to update.

Comment: Why not just use a `view`? e.g. `CREATE VIEW person_view AS SELECT *, CONCAT(email, mobile) AS info FROM person`? Then you don't have to update the table at all...

Answer (score 0):

This Statement:

I want to update the table based on the email address and mobile number. Since multiple records have the same email address and mobile number.

It seems like you have Unnormalized table

If you want to update with the same email and the same mobile number. Your update adding a bunch of same records repeatedly and its allocate a lot of space to your Database with redundant data.

I suggest why dont you create another table just for this?

For example:

You have a record of

```
PersoneID1 email1 Mobile1
PersoneID1 email1 mobile1
PersoneID1 email1 mobile1
PersoneID1 email1 mobile1
```

Instead of creating four `email1 Mobile1`

In your newly created table:

it just look like only one record something like:

```
PersoneID1 email1 Mobile1
```